# Delete a row from database using java GUI

Tags: java, sql

i am having a problem in deleting the row from database. as i get the selected row from model and then pass it to a database function but it gives me nullPointerException.
here is the code from GUI

```
 // getting the selected row
                int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();

                //converting the row index
                selectedRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);

                // getting values of the selected row
                String id = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);



                db.DeleteBooking(id);


                model.removeRow(selectedRow);


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Booking has successfully Cancelled");
```

and this the db function where i am passing the value.

```
 public void DeleteBooking(String x) throws SQLException
    {
        // openConnection is working successfully as my other queries are working.
     openConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps1=null;

    String query1="DELETE FROM booking WHERE id = ?";


        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);

    int y = Integer.valueOf(x);
    ps1.setInt(1, y);




    int row=ps1.executeUpdate();



    if(con!=null)
    {
        con.close();
    }


    }
```

can anyone please help me diagnose the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you all for reading but there was no problem in this code, the problem was in creating the db class object. i am so sorry for wasting you time.

Comment: that's fine, you can just delete your question in that case